# VS2019 install with SQL Server components causes err_connection_reset when viewing the web

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I installed Visual Studio 2019 last night with SQL Server components, and now whenever I try to view web pages in Chrome, I get a connection reset error. I assume it has something to do with IIS. I tried uninstalling IIS Express, but that didn’t seem to help. I checked all my connections and everything seems to be fine. I can ping google in the command line, but for some reason I just can’t view the web. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Have you checked if you can access web pages in edge or IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing all Visual studio installations and reinstalling VS 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your services are turned off, try entering the task manager with **CTRL + ALT + DELETE**, and look for SERVICES, the SQL SERVER server you are using, and check if it is **stopped**.

Answer (score 0):

> VS2019 install with SQL Server components causes err_connection_reset
>   when viewing the web

This is not expected behavior after VS installation. Maybe something in that installing process modified your IE settings.

Try resetting all IE options(IE options=>Advanced=>Reset) and reinstall Chrome browser.